# Can't find a way to use javascript + jquery to parse from URL and show it on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I'm a beginner in coding, i've learnt most of what I know about Jquery and Javascript from Codecademy.com



What I want to do (a little background before):

1. Hover over a specific link (partial url)
2. Get the full link content (for full url)
3. Parse the HTML contents of the link
4. Present the parsed data as a 'div' to show a "popup" with the data

So I used Jquery to hover over a specific link, so step 1 is completed.
I'm stuck on **step 2**.

Here is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var link_account = $("a[href^='http://www.example.com/info.php?ID=']");
    link_account.mouseenter(function () {
        var data2 = $(this).get({dataType: "html"});
        $(this).after(data2);
    });
});
```

What I tried to do in the code:

1. Wait for the document to load (**success**)
2. Find the partial link I want to use (**success**)
3. When my mouse hovers over it start an event (**success**)
4. Pull HTML from link (**failed**)

   IMPORTANT: I want to pull the HTML contents of the HTML page after I access the URL from the link. (I'm sorry if it wasn't clear)
5. Add the HTML code as a string after the link which should work - tested with other
   instances (**success**)

As you can see here I tried to use the $.get function in order to receive all of the HTML contents. But I guess I don't understand the concept quite correctly. I even tried to pass the URL to test it before I tried to pull the it from somewhere else, but it didn't help. I'm at loss here.

**note that when I tried to switch this `$(this).after(data2);` with:

```
$(this).after("<p>" + $(this).get() + "</p>");
```

I could see the full URL of the link, instead of the HTML contents.

I saw that there's also $.ajax but I'm not sure which one I should use in this case.

Some guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: This is probably because cross-domain, or are they all on your domain?

Comment: Cross-domain indeed, is there something I need to do in order to make it work on a different domain?

Comment: [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is a shorthand alternative to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), but you are using the (completely different) [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function with an invalid _index_. You need to be using `$.get()` to retrieve the contents of the URL via an AJAX request.

Comment: Nope, expect JSON-P or proxy

Comment: I want to load all the HTML code from a link - as though I'm clicking on it and loading a new page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the [AJAX `$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), but instead [this `.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) which is entirely different. That's why you are not getting the HTML from those links.

```
//step 1: Run on DOM ready
$(function() {

  //step 2 & 3: Get all links you want and add event handler
  $("a[href^='http://www.example.com/info.php?ID=']").on('mouseover',function(){

    //let's reference this link since the context will change in the get callback
    var link = this;

    //step 4: Use the href and get the HTML of that link
    $.get($(this).attr('href'),function(html){

      //step 5: Put the returned html after your link
      $(link).after(html);
    });
  });
});
```

Of course, [Same-Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) rules apply to AJAX. There's a lot of ways you can bypass it, just use the search. There are a lot of questions about it here. And don't forget to use the console of the browser. It tells you a lot about the errors that happen.

Comment: I see now you may want to add a text to your answer. because its very unclear

Comment: Hi I added the note "IMPORTANT: I want to pull the HTML contents of the HTML page after I access the URL from the link. (I'm sorry if it wasn't clear)"
To make it clearer as to what I'm looking for

Comment: Thank you Joseph, the tip about the console of the browser helps me a lot identifying why I had so much failure. I'm off to investigate as to why would I get "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: @lpolaright [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use this method: http://api.jquery.com/attr/
to retrieve the value of href.

so

```
url = $(this).attr("href");
```

or if it is the content you want:

```
html = $(this).html();
```

If you want replace or concatenate afterwards:

```
html += "<p>" + url + "</p>"
$(this).html(html)
```

`this` being the `<a>` in this exemple. Target a div or whatever you want by changing it to the appropriate selector.

Comment: I've added a comment: "IMPORTANT: I want to pull the HTML contents of the HTML page after I access the URL from the link. (I'm sorry if it wasn't clear)"

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that you problem was actually the get request. I guess the upper answer fixed it.

Comment: I want to simulate a person clicking on a link, pulling all the HTML of that page, and return it to the previous page as HTML code.

Comment: Ye, I get it now. The problem comes from your get request as mentionned above. And then just use the .html() method to insert it.